# Change order Analysis design files my project with Vivado HLS 2019

Tags: c, xilinx, vivado, synthesis, vivado-hls

I am using vivado xls from xlininx to create a top function. In my project there are 5 files:

- P434.c
- util.c
- sidh.c
- fpx.c
- crypt.c

When I run C Synthesys the analysis of the files starts with the following order:

1- util.c

2- sidh.c

3- P434.c

I would like the order analyzing file design to be:

1- util.c

2- P434.c

3- sidh.c

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

A specific compile order is necessary when one file has a declaration and another file
depends upon that declaration. The Vivado IDE controls RTL source files compilation from
the top of the graphical hierarchy shown in the Sources window Compile Order window to
the bottom.
The Vivado tools automatically identify and set the best top-module candidate, and
automatically manage the compile order. The top-module file and all sources that are under
the active hierarchy are passed to synthesis and simulation in the correct order.

To modify the compile order before synthesis, select a file, and right-click Hierarchy
Update > Automatic Update, Manual Compile Order so that the Vivado IDE can
automatically determine the best top module for the design and allows for manual
specification of the compilation order.

For more information regarding synthesis in vivado refer to this guide : 
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kartik,
but if I select a file and right-click NOT appears a menu "Hierarchy Update > Automatic Update".
Instead it appears a menu:

- copy;
- paste;
- delete;
- refresh;
- proprieties.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pylqC.png)

I use Vivado HLS Version 2019.1

why?